# Plugin - Htaccess redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a question. I've installed a plugin cache on my WordPress and I saw this in my htacess file. Does this mean that if I make my website live, it'll redirect to HTTPS? If so, how am I able to stop it?

```
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that if I make my website live, it'll redirect to HTTPS?

Nothing in the code you have posted will redirect to HTTPS.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
> RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
> RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
> ```

All this does is set the environment variable `W3TC_SSL` to "_ssl" if the site is accessed over HTTPS. If the site is accessed over HTTP then this variable is not set. They probably do this to help with constructing URLs to cached files.